# Unistalled apps still taking space on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, storage, aquaris

I'm using Ubuntu Touch 14.10 on the BQ Aquaris 4.5

Today I went to the `System Settings app -> About this phone -> Storage` and I'm able to see every app I have already unistalled. Also the ones I have upgraded are displayed twice (I suppose they would be displayed three times after the next app upgrade).

I tried rebooting the device and searching google but so far no luck with both.

Here's an example screenshot of what I'm talking about: 
[image: Screenshot @ imgur]

In the picture you can see the Music and My Photos apps two times and I've already removed Instagram Photos but it still shows it.

Everything is displayed normal on the Apps screen - upgraded apps are shown only once and uninstalled are not showing at all.

**//EDIT:**

The same thing keeps happening after the 15.04 update.

Comment: Furthermore, the space mentioned there may not be accurate. For example, I uninstalled the HERE app, but while the report says 113.7kB, the `~/.local/share/com.nokia.heremaps` directory is 30MB large.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bug over on Launchpad, dealing with the issue. It seems as of now the best thing to do is head over there and mark the bug as affecting you too in order to increase the bug heat. You may also subscribe to be notified about the bug (when it is resolved), this also counts towards the bug heat.

[Uninstalled Applications still using up space](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1434985)